# Error on copying AWS s3 bucket to Azure Storage using AZCopy

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-s3, azure-storage, azcopy

I have been trying to copy a AWS S3 bucket to my Azure Storage container following the Microsoft document [Amazon S3 to Azure Storage by using AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-s3)

But the operation fails with error as below

> **failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot start job due to error: cannot list objects, Access Denied.**

I have tried to copy by authentication through both Azure AD and also SAS token with Full Access privileges (racwdl) but get same issue.

I have verified that the AWS keys set are of admin access and also verified that both my AWS bucket and Azure Storage Containers are public.

What else could be wrong? Any inputs would be helpful.

Also sharing the terminal outputs on using AD authorization and SAS token authorization.

**On **AD Authorization:****

> INFO: Scanning... INFO: Authenticating to destination using Azure AD
> INFO: Instead of transferring from the 's3.amazonaws.com' URL, in this
> version of AzCopy we recommend you use a region-specific endpoint to
> transfer from one specific region. E.g. s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com or
> a virtual-hosted reference to a single bucket. INFO: Any empty folders
> will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have
> full folder support
>
> failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot start job due to
> error: cannot list objects, Access Denied.

**Using SAS Token Authorization**

> INFO: Scanning... INFO: Instead of transferring from the
> 's3.amazonaws.com' URL, in this version of AzCopy we recommend you use
> a region-specific endpoint to transfer from one specific region. E.g.
> s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com or a virtual-hosted reference to a single
> bucket. INFO: Failed to create one or more destination container(s).
> Your transfers may still succeed if the container already exists.
> INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or
> destination doesn't have full folder support
>
> failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot start job due to
> error: cannot list objects, Access Denied.

Comment: Hi Jerry, please refer to [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4800344) & paste the terminal output instead :)

Comment: And could you perhaps install the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html), run `aws configure` and then try to do `aws s3 ls` to see if you have the correct permissions AWS wise?

Comment: Looks like a permission issue on S3 side.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary  Thank you for your valuable input on posting images :). Also tried the aws s3 ls command and all s3 buckets are getting listed.

Comment: @GauravMantri Any permission in particular?

Comment: OK that's good - now try `aws s3 ls s3://[INSERT-BUCKET-NAME]`. What do you get? If your user/role has the `AdministratorAccess` managed policy attached, this should also work but double checking.

Comment: I would say check for list objects permissions.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Checked that too, i am able to list all the contents of the bucket.

Comment: @Jerry Run whatever this is, in debug mode or get logs - we need more info, clearly the error is not what its saying it is since you have access.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this issue. Apparently the solution is to add the AWS credentials as environment variables as setting them on CLI as mentioned in the documents doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, the powershell script "set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=....." doesn't work as it doesn't add the system environment variables in windows, so the access is denied to S3. To add the environment variables in Windows do the following:

1. Press Windows Key + R then open "control sysdm.cpl"
2. In System Properties click on Advanced -> Environment Variables
3. Under System Variables add the variable name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and place your access key under the value.
4. Add another system variable "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" and place in the AWS secret key.
5. Go back to powershell and you should be able to run azcopy and the permissions should work.
6. If the permissions still do not work, then it might be an issue with the permissions in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PowerShell to run the command, environment variables can be set as follows (without going into system variables)

```
$env:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$env:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="yyyyyyyyyyyy"
```

To list the environment variables in PowerShell, use

```
dir env:
```